# I'm getting an error here when I call my getChoice() method, and I don't know why

Tags: java

I'm getting an error where I call my getChoice() method, its saying variable footballTeam2 is already defined in the main method, why is that? Also am I calling my other method correctly? 
Thanks in advance guys, really could use some help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FootballGame { 
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int arewedone = 0;
    static String choice;
    static FootballTeam team;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FootballTeam footballTeam1;
    FootballTeam footballTeam2;

    System.out.print("Enter a name for a team:");
    footballTeam1 = new FootballTeam(keyboard.nextLine(), 0);
    System.out.print("Enter a name for another team:");
    footballTeam2 = new FootballTeam(keyboard.nextLine(), 0);

    do{
        System.out.println("Game Score:");
        System.out.println(footballTeam1.getName() + ":" + footballTeam1.getScore());
        System.out.println(footballTeam2.getName() + ":" + footballTeam2.getScore());

        choice = getMenuChoice(FootballTeam footballTeam1, FootballTeam footballTeam2);
        handleTeamScore(team);

    }while(arewedone == 0);
}

public static String getMenuChoice(FootballTeam footballTeam1, FootballTeam footballTeam2) {
    String input;

    do {
        System.out.println("Select an option:");
        System.out.println("A:" + footballTeam1 + " scored");
        System.out.println("B:" + footballTeam2 + " scored");
        System.out.println("C: game ended.");
        System.out.println("?:");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
            choice = (footballTeam1 + "");
            arewedone = 0;
        } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
            choice = (footballTeam2 + "");
            arewedone = 0;
        } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
            System.out.println("Game Over");
            arewedone++;
        }

    } while (!input.equals("A") && !input.equals("B") && !input.equals("C"));

    return choice;
}

public static void handleTeamScore(FootballTeam team) {

    int points;

    do {
        System.out.println("How many points were scored?");
        System.out.print("?: ");

        points = keyboard.nextInt();

        if ((team.addScore(points)) == true) {
            arewedone++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("That was an invalid option. Please try again.");
            System.out.println("Hints:");
            System.out.println("Touchdown = 6 points");
            System.out.println("Field Goal = 3 points");
            System.out.println("Safety = 2 points");
            System.out.println("Extra Point = 1 point");
        }
    } while (arewedone == 0);
}
```

}

Here's my other class with the addscore method and getters and setters.

```
public class FootballTeam {

private String name;
private int score;
public static int TOUCHDOWN = 6;
public static int FIELD_GOAL = 3;
public static int SAFETY = 2;
public static int TWO_POINT_CONVERSION = 2;
public static int EXTRA_POINT = 1;


public FootballTeam(String name, int score) {
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(int score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public boolean addScore(int points) {
    if (points == TOUCHDOWN || points == FIELD_GOAL || points == SAFETY || points == TWO_POINT_CONVERSION || points == EXTRA_POINT) {
        score = points + score;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean getMenuChoice and not getChoice?

Comment: Please format your code so it is readable (fix the indentation, remove the extra blank lines).  I see no `getChoice()` method. Did you mean `getMenuChoice()`?  Also, copy/paste the EXACT compiler message, don't paraphrase, and identify the exact line that caused the error.

Comment: Yes I do mean the the getMenuChoice method, and here's the compiler message, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: getMenuChoice
 at FootballGame.main(FootballGame.java:37)

Comment: That messsage means you ignored an error message at compile time.  Go back to the output of the compiler (javac or the compiler messages tab in your IDE) and add the compiler error message to your post.

Answer (score 1):

Change the method call

```
choice = getMenuChoice(FootballTeam footballTeam1, FootballTeam footballTeam2);
```

to this:

```
choice = getMenuChoice(footballTeam1, footballTeam2);
```

**EDIT**:

You need to initialize `FootballTeam team` before calling `handleTeamScore(team);`:

```
team = new FootballTeam(...);
handleTeamScore(team);
```

Change this code block of `getMenuChoice`:

```
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
            choice = (footballTeam1 + "");
            arewedone = 0;
        } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
            choice = (footballTeam2 + "");
            arewedone = 0;
```

to this :

```
public static String getMenuChoice(...){
...
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
            choice = "footballTeam1";
            arewedone = 0;
        } else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
            choice = "footballTeam2";
            arewedone = 0;
...
}
```

Now replace these two statements in `main`:

```
choice = getMenuChoice(footballTeam1, footballTeam2);
handleTeamScore(team);
```

to this:

```
choice = getMenuChoice(footballTeam1, footballTeam2);
if(choice != null) {
if(choice.equals("footballTeam1")){
team = footballTeam1;
}

if(choice.equals("footballTeam2")){
team = footballTeam2;
}
handleTeamScore(team);
}
```

Comment: Ah thankyou, now I'm getting this error for some reason, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at FootballGame.handleTeamScore(FootballGame.java:88)
 at FootballGame.main(FootballGame.java:39)

Comment: @user2934545 you are welcome. update your question to show exactly at which line you are getting this exception.

Comment: And also at handleTeamScore(team);

Comment: I edited my main post to show you my other class where the addscore method is.

Comment: What would my String and integer be for that though within my peramater?

Comment: because it requires a String and an integer in the parameter of that FootballTeam(....);

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your method wrongly

you should call it like this

```
choice = getMenuChoice1( footballTeam1,  footballTeam2);
```

by calling it like this

```
choice = getMenuChoice(FootballTeam footballTeam1, FootballTeam footballTeam2);
```

you confusing compiler whether you are calling a method or declaring a new one. We dont require to type the type while calling the method its implicit always